# Unique insertion of records in mongodb using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

For eg: I have inserted a record in mongodb as

> record_1 = {'name':'Surya','class':12}

Now if I try to insert the same value again in same collection than the insertion is successful. Like sql i want to avoid duplicate insertion. Moreover I don't have any unique key in my records.
Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique index on the collection.

MongoDB shell method:

```
db.mycollection.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Pymongo method:

```
import pymongo
db.mycollection.create_index([("name", pymongo.DESCENDING)], unique=True)
```